# java script codes don't work in phonegap 2.9.0

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have this code in my PhoneGap 2.9.0 application (for Windows Phone 7) but it doesn't work.

This is the code in the `index.js` file:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {
  var headertitle = document.getElementById('header1');
  headertitle.innerhtml+="phonegap..";
},
.
.
```

and this the code in the `index.html` file..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="header1">hello </h1><br/>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Of course I also include the Javascript in my `index.html` file.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

`headertitle.innerhtml`

is wrong

`headertitle.innerHTML`

is right

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
    `<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
function onDeviceReady() { 
var addContent ='phonegap..';document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML = addContent;

 }
</script>`